# Don't have CheckOut option in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am starting my own project with my team. I created an account in team foundation server and I could connect to the server.

Everything looks ok(I created a project and checked in it and I can see it in my tfs page) but when I try to checkout some files I don't have the CheckOut option. I can choose between Unchanged and Check In.

I checked the Server option in Source Control Settings

Comment: Have you tried editing a document? I think it should automatically check it out.

Comment: If I do that it will check out as unchanged

Comment: Is your user marked as a contributor to the project?

Comment: Yes my user is contributor and administrator

Answer (score 0):

Here's Microsoft's Official Documentation:

[Check out and edit files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181395.aspx)

TL;DR: You don't have to manually check out, just start editing and Visual Studio will automatically check it out for you.